# Problem with title page

Tags: titles, fancyhdr, scrpage2

I have the following title page:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt,chapterprefix=false]{scrbook}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\fancypagestyle{empty}{
\lhead{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{images/logo_black}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\rhead{\vspace*{-0.2cm}\includegraphics[height=1.4cm]{images/logo_black_blue.jpg}}
\fancyfoot{}
}

\vspace*{2cm}
\begin{center}
\Huge{\textbf{Title of Thesis}\\}

\large{Master Thesis\\[0.8cm]}
\LARGE{My Name\\}
\normalsize{Institute \\ My mail address}
\end{center}

\vfill
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\Large{\textbf Supervised by:} & \Large{Name 1}\\
\Large{} & \Large{Name 2}\\
                & \small{Institute}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\today\\
\end{center}

\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

The problem is now that I'm using scrpage2 instead of fancyhdr, that means fancypagestyle, lhead, headrulewidth, rhead and fancyfoot does not work.

How can this be corrected?

Comment: Please supply the community with a complete document we can compile. It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`...

Comment: Note that macros such as `\Huge` do not take arguments. They are switches.

Comment: @Werner I have added it.

Comment: @machinery: Why do you use a KOMA class and `fancyhdr`? Both may work together, most likely there will be problems. It's not recommended to use both in a document!

Comment: Using `fancyhdr` (or any other package for page headers/footers) on a titlepage is not a good idea. Please read [How to customize my titlepage?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/209993)

Comment: Package `scrpage` is obsolete and should be replaced by `scrlayer-scrpage`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `scrpage2` is outdated. Its successor is `scrlayer-scrpage`. There you can define an own layer page style for the title page:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt,chapterprefix=false]{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  head,
  addvoffset=\headsep,
  height=1.5cm,
  addheight=\dp\strutbox,
  contents={%
    \includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-image-A}%
    \hfill%
    \includegraphics[height=1.4cm]{example-image-B}%
  }
  ]{titlepage.head}
\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{titlepage}{titlepage.head}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{titlepage}
\vspace*{2cm}
\begin{center}
{\Huge \textbf{Title of Thesis}\par}
{\large Master Thesis\par\vspace{.8cm}}
{\LARGE My Name\par}
Institute \\ My mail address
\end{center}
\vfill
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\Large\textbf Supervised by: & \Large Name 1\\
& \Large Name 2\\
& \small{Institute}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\today
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

With the old package `scrpage2` it was also possible to define new page styles:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt,chapterprefix=false]{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\deftripstyle{titlepage}
  [0pt][0pt]
  {\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-image-A}}{}{\includegraphics[height=1.4cm]{example-image-B}}
  {}{}{}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{titlepage}
\vspace*{2cm}
\begin{center}
{\Huge \textbf{Title of Thesis}\par}
{\large Master Thesis\par\vspace{.8cm}}
{\LARGE My Name\par}
Institute \\ My mail address
\end{center}
\vfill
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\Large\textbf Supervised by: & \Large Name 1\\
& \Large Name 2\\
                & \small{Institute}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\today
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]